# Ergonomics: fingers to use to press Cmd and Opt keys at the same time

Tags: keyboard, ergonomics

I find myself struggling with keyboard shorts that require pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Opt</kbd> at the same time. I have been using my third and fourth fingers on my left hand press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>Opt</kbd> respectively, but this means for <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>, I have to use my right hand to press <kbd>s</kbd>.

I also tried using the thumb but sometimes I miss either the <kbd>Cmd</kbd> or <kbd>Opt</kbd>.

What is the preferred way to execute such keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: There's no preferred way to press key combinations - it's what works for ***you***.  Is there something that you're having difficulty with that it's not feasible for you?  If so, please detail so we can address a specific objective problem.

Comment: Try your thumb and fourth finger. But ultimately this is entirely subjective and will likely depend on whatever key you press in combination, as well as the physical layout (spacing) of your specific keyboard.

Comment: Since Apple is extremely conscious of their design choice, I'm pretty sure they figure it out hand and finger ergonomics when design their keyboard and shortcuts. Coming from Windows and Linux I can't adapt that quickly to Mac shortcuts, and I'd like some guidelines, specially on keyboard ergonomics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I need to hit <kbd>command</kbd> and either <kbd>control</kbd> or <kbd>option</kbd>,I generally use my left middle and fore fingers, sometimes middle and thumb, sometimes pinky and thumb.

However, it's not especially often I end up needing more than one modifier key at the same time (ie, I usually only need <kbd>command</kbd> or <kbd>option</kbd> or <kbd>control</kbd> with another key - not together).